# In a TextBlock, is it possible to select a specific word by touching it?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

In my application I have a TextBlock containing some words (like 20 or 25). I want the user to be able to tap a word in the TextBlock and retrieve it in the application to use it after.

Does anyone have an idea ?

I've tried with read only TextBox. But I need to tap it like 3 times to select a word in it and I can't do nothing with the copy & paste function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Simple answer :** you can't

**Work around :** use a `TextBox` re-styled to look like a `TextBlock`

```
TextBox box= new TextBox();
box.Style = (Style)App.Current.Resources["CopyTextBlock"];
```

Go [here](http://wp7trenches.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/copy-paste/) for the `"CopyTextBlock"` style.

And overload `GotFocus`:

```
box.GotFocus += textBox_GotFocus;
```

with:

```
private void textBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)sender;

    char[] strDataAsChars = txtBox.Text.ToCharArray();
    int i = 0;

    for (i = txtBox.SelectionStart - 1; ((i >= 0) && (strDataAsChars[i] != ' ')); --i) ;
    int selBegin = i + 1;

    for (i = txtBox.SelectionStart; ((i < strDataAsChars.Length) && (strDataAsChars[i] != ' ')); ++i) ;
    int selEnd = i;

    txtBox.Select(selBegin, selEnd - selBegin);
    Console.WriteLine("\n" + txtBox.SelectedText); 
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193027/selecting-the-tapped-on-word-on-a-single-click-in-textbox) for the GotFocus function.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a clue about win 7 programming specifically - but in WPF/winforms I'd capture the index/position of the cursor when the textbox gains focus, then find the word that begins/ends/surrounds that position and select that word?? Sorry if this is irrelevant, just thought I'd share.

Comment: +1 I didn't know it was possible to get the index of the cursor.

Comment: SelectionStart property?? I may be wrong, and like I say I've never sat down to win 7 programming, don't have a clue about it.

Comment: SelectionStart and such things are for TextBox. I use TextBlock to display text and they don't have such property.

Comment: Can you not use a textbox then and change it's properties to behave like a textblock? Assuming these would be: BorderThickness: 0,
IsReadOnly: True, IsReadOnlyCaretVisible: True, Cursor: Arrow in WPF - I don't know the equivalent properties in win 7.

Comment: I've tried read only TextBox re-styled to look like a TextBlock. But the focus with a read only TextBox in a grid does'nt seems to work well.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment about the focus in a grid. I don't know what else to suggest I'm afraid - given the right changes to the right properties you should be able to get a TextBox behaving exactly like a TextBlock, then you have access to the SelectionStart property and events that will let you achieve this. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Since this functionality is available in a textbox control, could you display your textblock content in a textbox, and restyle it to look like the textblock - that way you should get the copy functionality.

XAML Xnippet

```
<TextBox 
    Text="I am a textbox and my content is selectable" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    Width="400" 
    Height="100" 
    IsReadOnly="True" 
    Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" 
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
```

Seems to be part-way to the solution.  You would need to edit the styles in the VisualState for the control when it is active, but in principal this will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think tapping is a property of the `TextBox` and not the text inside it. So, if you want to be able to select a word by tapping it, I suggest you have a separate text box for every word (if your application allows that). You could make it look like a single text box if you want that.

If the number of words is not known in advance, you could programmatically add a text box every time a new word is added. You could have all the text boxes in a horizontal (or vertical, whichever suits you) list. So, it would be possible to scroll if the text gets too long.

Comment: It can be an idea but i think performances will drop with a large number of TextBlocks. I can have something like 10 TextBlock with 25 words each in a single scroll view...

Answer (score 0):

Just use VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates()
pass your current coordinates to it.
It will return List of UIElements hit by that coordinate.
in order to make sure TB is in that list you might like to pass Rect as parameter, in that case it will return list of UIElements hit by that rect.

If you want to show selected state and so on than you will have to determine position of text by visual transforms, and  draw Rect on top of your text.