# How call an event when click on part of text in text block?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

iHi, in my Windows Phone application in View I have:

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="lblink" FontSize="15" Margin="30,0,24,0"  Height="30" Text="*use a email@mail.com if you are not the member"  TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

I need to make the functionality like this: when I click on the text: "email@mail.com" it should be called an event

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you wanna that event redirect you to another page?

Comment: no it should fill another textblock

Comment: Go through this and have an idea

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193027/selecting-the-tapped-on-word-on-a-single-click-in-textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, try using following code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="*use a "/>
            <TextBlock Text="email@mail.com" Tap="TextBlock_Tap"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" if you are not the member"/>

        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: You can make it into UserControl with Email property and change when you need, if other text is static, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a `HyperlinkButton`. This allows you to set text in the `Content` property, and then implement the `Click` event handler.

Alternatively, you could use a Template for a button control:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <TextBlock x:Name="lblink" FontSize="15" Margin="30,0,24,0"  Height="30" Text="*use a email@mail.com if you are not the member"  TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    </ControlTemplate>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Which is implemented as follows:

```
<Button x:Key="MyButton" Template="{StaticResource MyButtonTemplate}" Click="MyButton_Click" />
```

You can then do whatever you need to in the `MyButton_Click` event handler.

Comment: As understood question, author wants fire event when user click on email address only.

Comment: Fair point Roman. The HyperlinkButton or Button method could easily be included as part of a horizontal stack panel with the content set to the email address only.

Answer (score 1):

```
                <TextBlock>
                    <Run Text="*use a " />
                    <Hyperlink Click="[click event]">
                        <Run Text="email@mail.com" />
                    </Hyperlink>
                    <Run Text=" if you are not the member" />
                </TextBlock>
```

This provides you the clickable region I think you are looking for.